# How to get name of product from many to many even if it is not in the related table SQL or EF linq query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to get all product names with category if even product doesn't have a category

[get informatoin for creation from here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryProduct
{
    public int CategoryProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

internal class EFDbContext : DbContext, IDBProductContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set ; }

    public EFDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFDbContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(p => p.CategoryProducts)
            .WithMany(c => c.Products)
            .Map(pc => {
                pc.MapLeftKey("ProductRefId");
                pc.MapRightKey("CategoryProductRefId");
                pc.ToTable("CategoryProductTable");
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

If I write a SQL query like this, I get all of them from joined EF table

```
SELECT p.Name, cp.Name 
FROM CategoryProductTable AS cpt, 
     CategoryProducts AS cp, Products as p
WHERE 
    p.ProductId = cpt.ProductRefId 
    AND cp.CategoryProductId = cpt.CategoryProductRefId
```

but I want to get all from product names with category if even product doesn't have a category

UPDATED: thanks for SQL solution @Nick Scotney, but now I would want know how it do it in Linq

Comment: When you say "How to do it in Linq" what exactly do you mean?  Is model Builder a a copy of all the tables, so you need to use Linq to query the data?

Comment: I got the desired result classically through the usual approach, EntityFramework supports the many to many structure and pulls out all the dependencies, but I'm learning LINQ and trying to do more through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be after a "LEFT OUTER JOIN" in your Sql?

```
SELECT
    p.Name,
    cp.Name
FROM
    Products p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CategoryProductTable cpt ON p.ProductId = cpt.ProductRefId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CategoryProducts cp ON cpt.CategoryProductRefId = cp.CategoryProductId
```

In the above SQL, everything from products will be selected, regardless of if there is a Category or not.  When there isn't a category, cp.Name will simply return NULL.

Comment: and tell me how to run your request? I don't get out

Comment: Where is your SQL that fetches the data from the database?

Comment: I did not pay attention, typos in the text. your solution helped me thank you very much. now it remains to figure out how to use this in linq

Answer (score 0):

You would want to remove `p.ProductId = cpt.ProductRefId` predicate if you want to show all products.

```
SELECT p.Name, cp.Name 
FROM CategoryProductTable as cpt, CategoryProducts as cp, Products as p
WHERE cp.CategoryProductId = cpt.CategoryProductRefId
```

This will assign each category to every product.

Comment: your answer outputs each product but it adds categories to those products that don't contain categories, in my case 4 product element doesn't contain categories but with your query it shows up as First Category and Second Category